# How does Augmented reality work?

Tags: image-processing, augmented-reality

Need some pointers to resources for learning about Image processing used in Augmented Reality. I'm doing a project/paper on image processing. I found Augmented Reality personally to be the coolest thing. I'd be very happy and grateful if someone could explain or point to books or web sites which explain all about the concepts behind the Image Processing in AR.

Thank You.

Comment: @Oded. How is that possible? The OP's question is a bit open and doesn't mention any implementation language; he is asking for resources on how the techniques involved in AR work. But AR definitely involves computers and programs, so I'd say it's very programming related.

Comment: I fear that people feel you are asking them to do you work for you, and the combination of *"I'm doing a project/paper on image processing."* and *"explain all about the concepts behind the Image Processing in AR"*  is a big part of *why* they might feel this way. In any case, this is a big, complicated field and you will need to start with some basics before you try to delve into a specialized sub-discipline. Moreover, the field tends to be very mathy, and if you just ask for expert help that is what you re going to get; if you don't want a lot of math you need to ask for the popular version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I know augmented reality is a set of methods to generate information on heads-up displays (think "Robocop"-style displays).  This field is currently divided into two major areas from an algorithmic standpoint:

- marker-based
- positional-based

*Marker-based* augmented reality is based on the computer processing artificial markers in the real world (examples: QR codes, barcodes, or similar markers) and superimpose computer-generated images based on where the markers are located.  This area requires significant image processing tasks done by the computer.  Ideally the computer will recognize real-world objects directly and thus the markers are no longer needed, but it is still a topic that requires much research.

*Positional-based* augmented reality is based on where you are located, where you are pointing to (as in heading), and where are the objects of interest are located relative to you.  The computer then will superimpose images on top of the real-world image gathered.  The computer doesn't need to do much image processing (almost none at all) except for superimposing the generated image on top of the camera image.

Of course some applications are hybrids of these techniques.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. They put things in perspective. It is the marker-based image processing that's of interest to me now. The ARtoolkit website does provide some info on their algorithms but for newbies like me each and every step has to be explained. So I guess I'll have to do a lot more learning in addition to the Image Processing course I'm doing at college. Thanks to all.